# importing files outside project causes mocha to fail on imports

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, babeljs

I have a project that has multiple code bases with shared code, ex of structure below:

```
|- project
    |- server
        |- package.json
        |- .babelrc
        |- ...
    |- client
        |- package.json
        |- .babelrc
        |- ...
    |- common
        |- constants
            |- http-codes.js
```

normally, I use a helpers.js file to specify modules required for tests that need to be run in mocha, example below:

```
require('@babel/polyfill');
require('@babel/register')({
  extensions: ['.js', '.ts', '.tsx'],
  presets: [
    '@babel/preset-env',
    '@babel/preset-typescript',
  ],
});
```

However if I try to run tests with files that import from outside the project I get errors indicating that the helpers.js file has not been applied to these files.

-- ex:

> (function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import {
>   inProductionMode } from '../utilities/environment';
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>       at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
>       at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
>       at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
>       at Module._compile (D:\license-server\apiServer\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
>       at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
>   ...

Is there a way to keep mocha happy without having to duplicate code between the applications that share certain data/utilities? I have been struggling to find a solution and am starting to think what I am trying to achieve is impossible with the Mocha framework.